# Erro de conversão no componente imageCropper do Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando fazer o corte de uma imagem com o componente `imageCropper` do Primefaces, mas nas implementações que realizei ele só dá erro de conversão, e quando não, o objeto `croppedImage` que o Primefaces implementa vem nulo. Obs.: O contexto da minha aplicação web é https. Nos meus testes quando coloco uma imagem qualquer da web de contexto https ele também dá erro. Já coloquei conversor e tudo, mas o conversor ele não chama! Please, I need help!

Segue trecho do código da página:

```
<div class="Container100 Responsive100 ContainerIndent">
                    <p:fileUpload auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.uploadBase64}"
                                  sizeLimit="1000000" fileLimitMessage="Atenção! Por favor, Anexe apenas uma foto!"
                                  multiple="false"
                                  label="Selecione uma foto"
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpg|jpeg|png)$/"
                                  update="imagemDeCorte2"/>
                </div>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:imageCropper id="imagemDeCorte2" value="#{fileUploadController.croppedImage}"
                                    image="#{fileUploadController.nomeImagemB64}"
                                    rendered="#{fileUploadController.nomeImagemB64}"
                                    initialCoords="0,0,354,472"
                                    aspectRatio="0.75"/>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Crop" action="#{fileUploadController.crop}"
                                 icon="ui-icon-scissors"/>
```

Código Java:

```
 public void uploadBase64(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

    arquivoFoto = event.getFile();

    String mimeType = FileUtils.detectMimeType(arquivoFoto.getContents());

    if (!arquivoFoto.getContentType().equals(mimeType)) {
        throw new IOException("Tipo do arquivo está errado: " + mimeType);
    }

    formatoFoto = arquivoFoto.getContentType();
    nomeFoto = arquivoFoto.getFileName();
    imageAsByteFoto = ByteBuffer.allocate(new Long(arquivoFoto.getSize()).intValue());

    try {
        InputStream is = arquivoFoto.getInputstream();

        //redimensiona a imagem
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
        BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT, 450, 600);

        arquivoFoto.getInputstream().read(imageAsByteFoto.array());
        ImagemBase64 ib4 = new ImagemBase64();

        String base64AsString = new String(Base64.encode(imageAsByteFoto.array()));
        ib4.setB64(base64AsString);
        ib4.setFormato(formatoFoto);
        ib4.setNome(nomeFoto);

        nomeImagemB64 = ib4.getSrc();
        nomeImagemB642 = ib4.getSrc();

        imagemFile = new File("imagemCortada.".concat(FilenameUtils.getExtension(nomeFoto)));
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(imagemFile, imageAsByteFoto.array());

        imagemCarregada = Base64.decode(ib4.getSrc());

        reload();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: No código que você postou não aparece o método crop, somente o de upload.

Comment: Verifique essa outra pergunta, pode ser que ajude em algo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4938/salvar-imagem-cortada-depois-do-upload

Comment: Adicionalmente, pode tentar também o JCrop http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html